# Multiple columns form submit in list collection in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have 4 textboxes that like A,B,C,D I have to take the values for previous year, present year and current year i.e multiple columns we can take can u tell me how to do.

Thanks in advance.

[See this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/comment-page-1/#comment-35729)   like multiple rows I have columns wise

Comment: Share here what you have tried?

Comment: I am new to spring give me idea to do how can i do it